# LINQ OUTER JOIN: How to display multiple columns from the right side table of the JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015

In the following [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) of `LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ`, suppose I add another property (column), say, `age` to the pet class. How can I display that `age` column in the following LINQ Query:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
{
    Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
    Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
    Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
    Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

    Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
    Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
    Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
    Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
    Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

    // Create two lists.
    List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
    List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

    var query = from person in people
                join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };

    foreach (var v in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.FirstName + ":", v.PetName);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: If I use `get.age` in the above query as shown below, I get the error: `the name pet does not exist in the current context`

```
var query = from person in people
                join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { person.FirstName, pet.age, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

Comment: the same way as you get single property. in the example, `subpet != null ? subpet.age : 0` etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev You mean, adding another object, say, PetAge` like `select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name), PetAge = (subpet == null ? 0 : subpet.age) }`

Comment: It's not another object, just another property. But yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @IvanStoev You may want to convert your comment to an answer with brief details - and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: That's pretty basic in order to be posted as answer. Thanks anyway for the kind proposal, really appreciate!